# Использование Сокет на примере игры в виселицу

Tags: java, сервер, сокет

Программа имеет client и server.
Программирую игру - виселицу. 
После того как server и client получили соединение происходит следующее:

1. Server спрашивает слово, которое надо загадать и отправляет его client.

   System.out.println("Please enter the word for the game:");

   ```
       word = scan.nextLine();
       out.println(word);
       System.out.println("Thank you! Now let client to guess...");
   ```
2. Client получает слово и спрашивает написать букву

   ```
       String inputLine = in.readLine();
       int length = inputLine.length();

       System.out.println("Server is connected");

       String letters;

       for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {

           System.out.println("PLease write a letter");
           letters = scan.nextLine();  
           out.println(letters);

           String fromServer = in.readLine();
           System.out.println(fromServer);

        }
   ```
3. Каждая буква отправляется server, там обрабатывается и приходит в виде ответа client (есть буква или нет, и где она расположена)п.с. все можно допустить пять ошибок при угадывании слова.

   ```
   char[] CharArr=word.toCharArray(); 
   char[] star = word.toCharArray();


   for(int i=0;i<star.length;i++)
   {
       star[i] = '*';
       System.out.print(star[i]);
       out.print(star[i]);
   }



      //only 5 prompts
      for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
      {
       for (int j=0;j<CharArr.length; j++)
       {
         //Read letter from client
           String inputLine = in.readLine();
           char letter=inputLine.charAt(0);
           if(letter == star[j])
           {
               out.printf("This letter already exist!");
               System.out.println("This letter already exist!");
           }
           else
           {
               if(letter==CharArr[j])
               {
                   star[j]=letter;
                   i--;
                   out.println("Correct guess!\n");
                   System.out.println("Correct!");
               }
           }
       }
       out.println(star);
       switch(i+0)
       {
               case 1: out.println("Mistake 1\n");
                   break;
               case 2: out.println("Mistake 2\n");
                   break;
               case 3: out.println("Mistake 3\n");
                   break;
               case 4: out.println("Mistake 4\n");
                   break;
               case 5: out.println("Mistake 5\n");
               out.printf("You are wrong\n");
               System.out.printf("You are wrong!");
                   break;


   }
       out.println("\n");
       if((new String(word)).equals(new String(star))) 
       {
           out.println("Yes! You are the champion!\n");
           System.out.printf("Winner!");
           break;
       }

   }
   ```

**1. Сlient абсолютно рандомно пишет ответы на разные буквы и я не понимаю, достаточно ли этой строчки, чтобы получать ответы от server.**

```
String fromServer = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(fromServer);
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: А почему вы не проверяете, сколько ввёл символов пользователь? Если 0, то у вас будет тот самый Exception

Comment: Спасибо, я исправила